# Ubuntu automatically logging out within 10 minutes

Tags: ubuntu

I have been running Ubuntu for a week and it's been pretty painful so far, but I would really like to leave Windows for Ubuntu, because it's free, open-source and all that is good.

Ubuntu always logs my computer out within 10 minutes when I am using it. The log-out often combines with an 'enter'-keystroke. After logging in again, the issue will not return. After a reboot, within 10 minutes, X will crash when using it.

You can view the logfile at http://www.codepad.eu/view/raw/70522425, but hasn't helped me much in tracing the issue.

Comment: that link is currently broken.

Comment: Logs out even when you work with computer? Or when idle? Does it actually lock the screen or logs out? If while idle, yo should check screensaver properties - there you can set/unset whether to lock the screen when going to sleep.

Comment: Janis: It logs out. Not when idle. When I work and seems always when I press an enter. It's not a lock screen.

Comment: Janis: All software, all programs are closed when it logs out. So I can assure you, it's not the lock screen. It effectively means I can't do anything the first 10 minutes until the first logout or risk losing work.

Comment: Try this and it might solve your problem-
https://askubuntu.com/a/772783/689401

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've a problem with the ATI drivers, try to install the [last update](http://www.amd.com/es/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-5700/Pages/ati-mobility-hd-5700.aspx) and reconfigure the ati/xorg files as was [said at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7430/how-to-generate-xorg-conf-x-configure-segfaults)

Comment: Thanks. The ATI.com drivers (I installed early week) could very well be related. I am going to update and test immediately. If the issue is not solved, I will see if the default drivers have the same issue and maybe switch to the ATI open-source drivers to not have this issue, but still have dual monitor setup.